# How to get current user using WSS 3.0 & Membership provider inside ItemDeleting event receiver method?

Tags: .net-3.5, sharepoint-2007, wss-3.0, sharepoint-api

I need to get current user name in my Wss 3.0 application. What is more I would like to do this inside ItemDeleting method which is inside event receiver for SPList.
I've tried SPContext and HttpContext objects but they doesn't work. I have to add that I'm using Membership Provider and SQL Role provider. I'm not using Active Directory.
Can anybody help me and tell is there a way to obrain currently logged in user name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public override void ItemDeleting(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    using (SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPUser user = web.AllUsers.GetByID(properties.CurrentUserId);
    }
}
```

No need for HttpContext or SPContext. :-)